# Select Data from Database, using Today's Date as criteria

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server-express

I have a winform C#/SQL Project going on, 
Where in I have a datatable where data is stored with corresponding time stamp, E.G. when a user registers a complaint the exact/near enough timestamp is stored in the table. it is stored in "MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss" format, the table column is of "datetime".

i have a need to select all the entries in the table where the date is today's...
so far here is my code..

```
SqlConnection tod1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=2011-GOA-RCC3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=IOB_Comm;Integrated Security=True");
tod1.Open();
SqlCommand todc1 = new SqlCommand();
todc1.Connection = tod1;

DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
//DateTime todayl = today.AddDays();
DateTime dnext = today.AddDays(1);
label4.Text = today.ToString("MMM dd yyyy 00:00");
label5.Text = dnext.ToString("MMM dd yyyy 00:00");
label6.Text = label4.Text;
label7.Text = label5.Text;

DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(label4.Text);
DateTime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(label5.Text);
dateTimePicker3.Value = today;
dateTimePicker4.Value = dnext;

var d3 = Convert.ToString(label4.Text);
var d4 = Convert.ToString(label5.Text);
//todc.CommandText = "Select * from DCR Where Comp_Date >= '" + d1 + "' And Comp_Date <= '" + d2 + "' Order By Comp_Date Asc";
//todc.CommandText = "Select * from DCR Where Comp_Date '" + DateTime.Today + "'Order by Comp_Date Asc";
todc1.CommandText = "Select * from DCR Where Comp_Date >= '"+ dateTimePicker3.Text +"' And Comp_Date < '"+dateTimePicker4.Text+"' Order By Comp_Date Desc";
int a = todc1.ExecuteNonQuery();
label8.Text = a.ToString();
if (a > 0)
{
    //bind to report viewer
}
```

but the `int a = todc1.ExecuteNonQuery();` Always returns -1. so I diagnosed that my query is not executing correctly.

I've tried a many lot of approaches but none of them work, whats more troubling is that a similar query executes perfectly in SQL.

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` always returns `-1` because your command is `SELECT`. Read the documentation please.

Comment: This is **NOT** good! What does this date (as a string) mean: 05/03/2014? Is it 5th March or 3rd May? Use universal YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Use [ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: @SonerGönül O.k. Understood your point, so how do i proceed furhter?
even if i were to remove the int a =todc1.execurteNonQuery, the select query still does not return the columns with todays date ranging from say e.g FEB 28 2014 00:00:00 to MAR 01 2014...

Comment: @JohnnyMopp i have another form where i use two datetimepicker controls to choose two independent date, like say FEB 25 2014  and FEB 28 2014... that query retruns all the rows between those two days. i have also used executeNonquery instead of Execute Reader. it works like a charm...

Answer (score 6):

You need to get set of rows back from your query, currently you are using `ExecteNonQuery` which is usually used for `INSERT/Updates`. You also need to **parametrized your query** instead of passing formatted dates, you can simplify your code like:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
    using (SqlCommand todc1 = new SqlCommand("Select * from DCR Where Comp_Date >= @todayDate And Comp_Date < @nextDay Order By Comp_Date Desc", conn))
    {
        todc1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@todayDate", DateTime.Today);
        todc1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nextDay", DateTime.Today.AddDays(1));

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(todc1.ExecuteReader());
        //bind to report viewer. 
        //yourReportViewer.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

This will fill a `DataTable` from your query and later you can bind that to your report viewer. You should also enclose your `Connection` and `Command` object in [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx).

Comment: Good answer as covers `ExecuteReader` AND handling dates AND parameters - everyone should know who little Bobby Tables is! :-) https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Does `AddWithValue` format the `DateTime` to MySQL's 'YYYY-MM-DD' format prior to running the query against the database?

Comment: @DerekW, That is the purpose of Parameters, You don't have to specify format. If your column type is `DateTime` it will be fine. However, you are using MySQL or SqlServer, because your code is using classes for `SqlServer`, if you are targeting MySql Database then use MySql classes

Comment: Well I'm not the OP. I was just a curious bystander. I always format my `DateTime` to the correct format for use with the RDBMS, but it appears that the functionality of `AddWithValue` within ADO.NET is already doing that for me.

Comment: @DerekW, My bad :), Yes, formatting `DateTime` for using in SQL queries through .Net framework *(or any other)* for that matter is not really a good idea. Most frameworks supports parameters with queries, they will be helpful for resolving formatting issues and also saves one from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Oh I'm a zealot when it comes to parameterized queries (Added Performance + Security). I just didn't know that it was already translating C#'s `DateTime` format into the `DATETIME` format of the RDBMS that I was interfacing with.

Answer (score 1):

The SqlCommand method ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE commands. For SELECT statements, it always returns -1.

You should remove the `if (a > 0)` condition, as this will always return false.

Also, if you are using an object of DateTimePicker class in your GUI, you should use the Value property rather than the Text property.

Comment: I don't think this is what OP is after. They want to know to use `ExecuteReader` and read records (show on a report).

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlConnection.Open();
sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
sqlCommand.CommandText = "Select * from DCR Where Comp_Date >= @CurrentDate And Comp_Date < @nextDay Order By Comp_Date Desc";

sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@CurrentDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = adparam[0];
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@NextDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = adparam[1];
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

sqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcommand);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
```